# Get a Random Item from an Array

Tags: arrays, asp-classic

I am starting with this basic code sample:

```
<%
block1 = "tree, ball, cheese, rabbit, waffle, planet, string, cat, dog, hole, hobbit, sing,"

wordArray1 = split(block1, ",")

For Each item In wordArray1
    Response.Write(item & "<br />")
Next

max=11
min = 1
Randomize
rand1 = Int((max-min+1)*Rnd+min)

response.write "<hr/>rand1: " & rand1 & "<hr/>"

w1 = wordArray1(0,rand1)

response.write "w1: " & w1 & "<hr/>"
%>
```

I start with a list of words split by commas (block1).

I convert that into an array (wordArray1)

I can prove that array exists by looping through it and printing the array values to the page.

I then would like to be able to randomly select just 1 value from that array.

I thought I could just do something like:

```
max=11
min = 1
Randomize
rand1 = Int((max-min+1)*Rnd+min)

response.write "<hr/>rand1: " & rand1 & "<hr/>"

w1 = wordArray1(0,rand1)
```

But I get this error:

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0009'
Subscript out of range: 'wordArray1'
```

How can I randomly access one of the array?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not creating a multidimensional array so you should not be passing in two parameters. Change this line:

```
w1 = wordArray1(0,rand1)
```

to this:

```
w1 = wordArray1(rand1)
```